# Android EditText inputType="numberDecimal" only shows correct keyboard on second tap

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

The first time I tap an EditText with `inputType="numberDecimal"`, I get a full keyboard. The second time I tap on it, I get a correct decimal keyboard, and every subsequent tap on other EditTexts has the correct keyboard as well.

Why does the wrong keyboard come up on first tap?

Edit: Code.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:padding="10dp"
        >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dip"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Power Clean"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:id="@+id/lift_name"
                  android:layout_weight="3"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dip"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="260.12"
                  android:id="@+id/max"
                  android:layout_weight="2"
                  android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dip"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/training_max"
                  android:layout_weight="2"
                  android:text="234.78"
                  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly Post some code.

Comment: I tried and am getting numeric keyboard on the first as well as second attempt. Jellybean 4.2.2 rooted

Comment: How are you setting inputType in EditText??

Comment: Please, check if you don't have two overlapping edittexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `EditText` inside a `ListView`, then the `ListView` will cause a number of bugs in the `EditText`. You need to set this on the activity:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

...and this on the `ListView`:
`getListView().setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);`

Comment: This worked. My problem was whenever I had `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` on my `EditText`, it would immediately lose focus after selecting.